# Add action button view/delete in react table tenstack library

Tags: reactjs, redux, tailwind-css, react-table

i have a list of employees being fetched from an api.
i am uisng react-table(tenstack) library to use display it.
i want to add action buttons view/delete on each row and add an event to view or delete a employee. please help on this.
below is the code snipped for rendering table

```
  import { useTable, useGlobalFilter, usePagination, useRowSelect } from 'react-table'
  const columns =COLUMNS
  const data = employees
  const {
  getTableProps,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  footerGroups,
  rows,
  selectedFlatRows,
  state,
  setGlobalFilter,
  page,
  nextPage,
  previousPage,
  canNextPage,
  canPreviousPage,
  pageOptions,
  setPageSize,
  gotoPage,
  pageCount,
  prepareRow
  } = useTable({
 columns,
 data,
 initialState: {
  pageIndex: 0
 
 },

useGlobalFilter,
usePagination,
useRowSelect
)


<table {...getTableProps()} className="items-center mt-4 w-full bg-transparent border-collapse">
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-xs whitespace-nowrap p-4" {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th className={
                  "px-6 font-extrabol align-middle border border-solid py-2 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap  text-left " +
                  (color === "light"
                    ? "bg-blueGray-50 text-blueGray-500 border-blueGray-100"
                    : "bg-theme font-extrabold   text-white")
                } {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-xs whitespace-nowrap p-4" {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td className="px-6 py-4 text-black font-bold align-middle border-2 whitespace-nowrap text-left"  {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot className='font-bold'>
          {footerGroups.map(footerGroup => (
            <tr className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 border-r-0 text-xs whitespace-nowrap p-4" {...footerGroup.getFooterGroupProps()}>
              {footerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <td className={
                  "px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-2 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold text-left " +
                  (color === "light"
                    ? "bg-blueGray-50 text-blueGray-500 border-blueGray-100"
                    : "bg-theme font-extrabold   text-white")
                } {...column.getFooterProps()}>{column.render('Footer')}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

please help how to add action buttons on each row and perform events base don employee code